# How do I add a copy button to a WPF messagebox in a PowerShell script?

Tags: wpf, powershell

I've been using a PowerShell script from [this blog](https://smsagent.blog/2017/08/24/a-customisable-wpf-messagebox-for-powershell/) (script at the bottom) to create a messagebox for users to tell them what their VPN username is.  What I want to do is add a copy button so that the user can copy the username. Below is some extra code that has been added at the end of the script to launch the message box.  Currently all that shows is an OK button.  I do not know WPF at all and I am trying to keep within the framework of the blog author's script.  I've also included a picture of what the messagebox looks like.

[image]

```
# Read content of VPN_username.txt, if it exists.
if (Test-Path -Path "$env:SystemDrive\Temp\VPN_username.txt") {

    $VPNUserName = Get-Content -Path "$env:SystemDrive\Temp\VPN_username.txt" -Force
}


# Load WPF assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Create a richtextbox to display the completion summary with hyperlinks
$RTB = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox
$RTB.Padding = 5
$RTB.IsDocumentEnabled = $true
$RTB.IsReadOnly = $true
$RTB.BorderThickness = 0
$RTB.MaxWidth = 370
$RTB.FontFamily = "Segui"
$RTB.FontSize = 14
    $FlowDocument = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument
        $Paragraph = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph
            $Run = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.Run
            $Run.Text = "The VPN username that you last used is $VPNUserName" 
        $Paragraph.AddChild($Run)
    $FlowDocument.AddChild($Paragraph)
$RTB.AddChild($FlowDocument)


# Display the messagebox.
New-WPFMessageBox -Content $RTB -Title "Cisco Secure Client Upgrade" -TitleFontSize 24 -TitleBackground MidnightBlue -TitleTextForeground White -Sound 'Windows Notify'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is possible using custom buttons that you pass to the function on the blog post you linked to. Using one of the examples on the blog we can create a hashtable with the parameters and add `CustomButtons` with the desired text and pass that to `New-WPFMessageBox`.

```
$params = @{
    Content = $RTB
    Title = "Cisco Secure Client Upgrade"
    TitleFontSize = 24
    TitleBackground = "MidnightBlue"
    TitleTextForeground = "White"
    Sound = 'Windows Notify'
    ButtonType = "None"
    CustomButtons = "OK", "COPY"
} 
# original
# New-WPFMessageBox -Content $RTB -Title "Cisco Secure Client Upgrade" -TitleFontSize 24 -TitleBackground MidnightBlue -TitleTextForeground White -Sound 'Windows Notify'

New-WPFMessageBox @params
```

It is also possible to create actions on those buttons.

> "When a button is clicked, the text of the button is saved to a
> variable named WPFMessageBoxOutput so you can handle this in your code
> and perform different actions depending on what was clicked, eg"

Modifying the example code for the above named buttons we can do this:

```
If ($WPFMessageBoxOutput -eq "COPY")
{
    Set-Clipboard -Value $VPNUserName
}
ElseIf ($WPFMessageBoxOutput -eq "OK")
{
  EXIT
}
```

It will copy the value of `$VPNUserName` using [Set-Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-7.3) to the clipboard and exit if "ok" is pushed.

Putting it together with the rest of the code the same.

```
# Load WPF assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Create a richtextbox to display the completion summary with hyperlinks
$RTB = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox
$RTB.Padding = 5
$RTB.IsDocumentEnabled = $true
$RTB.IsReadOnly = $true
$RTB.BorderThickness = 0
$RTB.MaxWidth = 370
$RTB.FontFamily = "Segui"
$RTB.FontSize = 14
    $FlowDocument = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument
        $Paragraph = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph
            $Run = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.Run
            $Run.Text = "The VPN username that you last used is $VPNUserName" 
        $Paragraph.AddChild($Run)
    $FlowDocument.AddChild($Paragraph)
$RTB.AddChild($FlowDocument)

$params = @{
    Content = $RTB
    Title = "Cisco Secure Client Upgrade"
    TitleFontSize = 24
    TitleBackground = "MidnightBlue"
    TitleTextForeground = "White"
    Sound = 'Windows Notify'
    ButtonType = "None"
    CustomButtons = "OK", "COPY"
} 
# Display the messagebox.
# New-WPFMessageBox -Content $RTB -Title "Cisco Secure Client Upgrade" -TitleFontSize 24 -TitleBackground MidnightBlue -TitleTextForeground White -Sound 'Windows Notify'
New-WPFMessageBox @params
If ($WPFMessageBoxOutput -eq "COPY")
{
    Set-Clipboard -Value $VPNUserName
}
ElseIf ($WPFMessageBoxOutput -eq "OK")
{
  EXIT
}
```